# How to deal with ProGuard after renaming packages and class names

Tags: android, proguard

I've completely changed the names and packages of almost all of my classes, none of the original packages and names have remained.
Now, if I upgrade from my Google Play Store app version to my new app version, I get crashes like this:

`Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.android.storage.b.a(java.util.Observer)' on a null object reference
                                                       at com.example.android.domain.e.b.d(MyClass.java:427)`

I am guessing this has something to do with ProGuard

how do I tell proguard about the change in package and class names?
should I just declare the `keep`s to point to the new directions or should I somehow provide a mapping between new and old classes

Comment: You only have to change the `keep`s to point to the new package/class names. There is no need to reference the old names. However, from a first glance, your issue does not seem to be related to Proguard. You should check your MyClass.java class at line 427. It seems that you are calling a method on a null item there. Also, you could check if Proguard is the culprit, by disable-ing it and checking if you encounter the same issue.

Comment: @Vlad this issue started when I enabled Proguard, as I had kept it set to off for quite some time, so I guess Proguard might be the problem. I will follow your advice and write back